# Appium Webdriverio Setup

Tags: node.js, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I need help understanding how to set up a testing framework to using Appium, Webdriverio, Node.js, Jasmine.  I have the wdio.conf.js file set up:

```
 host: '127.0.0.1',

port: 4723,

path:  '/wd/hub',
```

....

```
specs: [
        './spec/wdtest/test.js'
    ],
```

....

```
capabilities: [
        {
            automationName: "appium",
            browserName: 'iOS',
            commandTimeout: '7200',
            sessionOverride: true,
            debugLogSpacing: true,
            platformVersion: '10.1',
            platformName: 'iOS',
            showIosLog: true,
            deviceName: 'iPhone 6s',
            nativeInstrumentsLib: true,
            isolateSimDevice: true,
            autoLaunch: true,
            app: '/Users/fodgerl/Library/Developer/Xcode/...../Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app'
        }
    ],
```

....

```
services: ['appium'],

    appium: {
        args: {
            address: '127.0.0.1',
            commandTimeout: '7200',
            sessionOverride: true,
            debugLogSpacing: true,
            platformVersion: '10.1',
            platformName: 'iOS',
            deviceName: 'iPhone 6s',
            showIosLog: true,
            nativeInstrumentsLib: true,
            isolateSimDevice: true,
            app: '/Users/fodgerl/Library/...../Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app'
        }
    },

    framework: 'jasmine',
```

My package.json file has:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "wdio wdio.conf.js"
  },
```

And I have a test js file that has this:

```
describe('test', function() {
    it('test', function () {
        //how do I interact with the app?

        console.log("HEREEEEE");
    });
});
```

When I run npm test, the simulator launches and the app launches within it. What I don't know is where to go to next?  How do I open app/interact with elements/etc.

I have seen examples like:

```
var client = webdriverio.remote({
    port: 4723,
    logLevel: 'verbose',
    desiredCapabilities: {
        platformName: 'iOS',
        platformVersion: '8.4',
        deviceName: 'iPhone 6',
        app: webviewApp
    }
});
```

But do I need to do that if I already have the simulator up and running from the stuff in the conf file? I was trying to find some documentation on what .remote(), init(), etc does.  Also, I looked in the Launcher for webdriverio but I couldn't determine where/how it was being used in the example here: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio/runner-specs/jasmine.spec.js

Any help would be appreciated to get me started!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On running `$ npm test`, it executes `$ ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js`. So you have the wdio test runner up and running.

Now, as mentioned in [The Browser Object](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/browserobject.html) subsection:

> If you use the wdio test runner you can access the webdriver instance through the global `browser` object. The session is initialized by the test runner so you don’t need to call `init` command. The same goes for ending the session. This is also done by the test runner process.

That's it! You can access the driver instance via the global variable `browser` as illustrated in the aforementioned [example](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio/runner-specs/jasmine.spec.js).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

webdriver.io is just for running the tests. Not interacting with the app. Use appium to app/interact with elements/etc. Appium will record the step and elements path/s. From here you can create your test cases which can be run using wedriver.io

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should start with [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) for running the appium server
and using [Appium Inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector) to launch your app and inspect for elements, get locators and add them to your code