# There is a problem with Appium / WebdriverIO that the test does not start from WebdriverIO

Tags: android, appium, webdriver-io

There is a problem with **Appium / WebdriverIO** that the test does not start from WebdriverIO

They run flawlessly

- adb.exe

  o   adb devices
  o   List of devices attached
  o   emulator-5554   device
- appium inspector
- Vysor
- appium server

  - [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
  - [Appium] Non-default server args:
  - [Appium] address: 127.0.0.1
- android studio

I have tried both emulated and real phones, I can't connect to any of them, it doesn't contact with them
Following this page, https://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/ works with both devices.
WDIO config (I only took out the important items)

```
exports.config = {
runner: "local",
port: 4723,
path: "/wd/hub",

specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js'
    ],
capabilities: [{
        platformName: "Android",
        "appium:platformVersion": "11",
        "appium:deviceName": "SM-G715FN",
        "appium:app": "C:\\\\Downloads\\ApiDemos-debug.apk",
        "appium:appPackage": "com.wdiodemoapp",
        "appium:appActivity": ".MainActivity",
        "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2"
}],
baseUrl: 'https://localhost',
framework: 'mocha',
reporters: ['spec'],
mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        require: ['@babel/register'],   //////
        timeout: 60000
    },

services: 
        [
            ['appium',
                {args:{
                    debugLogSpacing: true,
                    "base-path": "wd/hub"
                        },
                command: 'appium',
                },
            ],                
        ],

package.json
{
  "name": "webdriverio-tests",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/register": "^7.17.7",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^7.13.2",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.19.7",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.19.7",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.19.7",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.19.7",
    "appium-uiautomator2-driver": "^2.1.2",
    "appium-xcuitest-driver": "^4.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-wdio": "^7.19.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.19.7",
    "appium": "^2.0.0-beta.35",
    "wdio-image-comparison-service": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "description": "Appium tests using WebdriverIO",
  "main": "wdio.conf.js",
  "keywords": [
    "webdriverio",
    "appium"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


Test
describe('Sample', () => {
    it('Connect', async () => {
const field = await client.$("android.widget.EditText");
await field.setValue("Hi Sir!");
await client.deleteSession();
 });
```

Test failed:
Request failed with status 404 due to The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[POST] http://localhost:4723/session

I checked this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828114/appium-webdriverio-setup",but it didn't help.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line

```
baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
```

instead of

```
baseUrl: 'https://localhost',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.config = {

    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    // default appium port


    //
    // ====================
    // Runner Configuration
    // ====================
    //
    //
    // ==================
    // Specify Test Files
    // ==================
    // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
    // from which `wdio` was called.
    //
    // The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
    // that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
    // worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
    // process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
    //
    // If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
    // then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
    // will be called from there.
    //
    specs: [
         './features/*.feature'

       
    ],
    suites: {
       
        // otherFeature: [
        //     // ...
        // ]
    },
    // Patterns to exclude.
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    //
    // ============
    // Capabilities
    // ============
    // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
    // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
    // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
    // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
    //
    // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
    // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
    // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
    // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
    // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
    // from the same test should run tests.
    //
    maxInstances: 10,
    //
    // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
    // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
    // https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
    //
    capabilities: [{




        //Android 
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                '--disable-popup-blocking',
                '--disable-notifications'
            ],
        },

        deviceName: "Android Emulator",
        platformVersion: "12",
        platformName: "Android",
        //driver downloaded from chromedriver website
        chromedriverExecutable: "chromedriver",
        orientation: "PORTRAIT",
        gpsEnabled: true,
        autoGrantPermissions: true,


        // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
        // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
        // 5 instances get started at a time.
        maxInstances: 1,



        acceptInsecureCerts: true
        // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
        // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    }],
    //
    // ===================
    // Test Configurations
    // ===================
    // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
    //
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    logLevel: 'error',

    //
    // Set specific log levels per logger
    // loggers:
    // - webdriver, webdriverio
    // - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
    // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
    // - @wdio/local-runner
    // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
    // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
    // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
    // logLevels: {
    //     webdriver: 'info',
    //     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
    // },
    //
    // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
    // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
    bail: 0,
    //
    // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
    // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
    // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
    // gets prepended directly.
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost/',
    //
    // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.

    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //waitforTimeout: 156000,

    //
    // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
    // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
    connectionRetryTimeout: 12000,
    //
    // Default request retries count
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    // Test runner services
    // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
    // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
    // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.

    services: ['appium'],

    // Framework you want to run your specs with.
    // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
    //
    // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
    // before running any tests.
    framework: 'cucumber',
    //
    // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
    // specFileRetries: 1,
    //
    // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
    // specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
    //
    // Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
    // specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
    //
    // Test reporter for stdout.
    // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
    reporters: ['spec'],



    //
    // If you are using Cucumber you need to specify the location of your step definitions.
    cucumberOpts: {
        // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features
        require: ['./features/step-definitions/*.steps.js'],
        // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
        backtrace: false,
        // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
        requireModule: [],
        // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
        dryRun: false,
        // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
        failFast: false,
        // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
        snippets: true,
        // <boolean> hide source uris
        source: true,
        // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
        strict: false,
        // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
        tagExpression: '',
        // <number> timeout for step definitions
        timeout: 156000,
        // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
        ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false
    },

    //
    // =====
    // Hooks
    // =====
    // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
    // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
    // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
    // resolved to continue.
    /**
     * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     */
    // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    //     //removeSync('reporter1/json');
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialise specific service
     * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
     * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
     * @param  {[type]} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker
     * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
     * @param  {[type]} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialised
     * @param  {[type]} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
     */
    // onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
     * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {String} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)
     */
    // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
     * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {Object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
     */
    // before:async function (capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
     * @param {String} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     */
    // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
    // },
    /**
     * Cucumber Hooks
     *
     * Runs before a Cucumber Feature.
     * @param {String}                   uri      path to feature file
     * @param {GherkinDocument.IFeature} feature  Cucumber feature object
     */
    // beforeFeature: function (uri, feature) {

    // },
    /**
     *
     * Runs before a Cucumber Scenario.
     * @param {ITestCaseHookParameter} world    world object containing information on pickle and test step
     * @param {Object}                 context  Cucumber World object
     */
    // beforeScenario: function (world, context) {

    // },
    /**
     *
     * Runs before a Cucumber Step.
     * @param {Pickle.IPickleStep} step     step data
     * @param {IPickle}            scenario scenario pickle
     * @param {Object}             context  Cucumber World object
     */
    // beforeStep: function (step, scenario, context) {
    // },
    /**
     *
     * Runs after a Cucumber Step.
     * @param {Pickle.IPickleStep} step             step data
     * @param {IPickle}            scenario         scenario pickle
     * @param {Object}             result           results object containing scenario results
     * @param {boolean}            result.passed    true if scenario has passed
     * @param {string}             result.error     error stack if scenario failed
     * @param {number}             result.duration  duration of scenario in milliseconds
     * @param {Object}             context          Cucumber World object
     */
    // afterStep: async function (step, scenario, result, context) {

      

    // },
    /**
     *
     * Runs after a Cucumber Scenario.
     * @param {ITestCaseHookParameter} world            world object containing information on pickle and test step
     * @param {Object}                 result           results object containing scenario results
     * @param {boolean}                result.passed    true if scenario has passed
     * @param {string}                 result.error     error stack if scenario failed
     * @param {number}                 result.duration  duration of scenario in milliseconds
     * @param {Object}                 context          Cucumber World object
     */
    // afterScenario: function (world, result, context) {
    // },
    /**
     *
     * Runs after a Cucumber Feature.
     * @param {String}                   uri      path to feature file
     * @param {GherkinDocument.IFeature} feature  Cucumber feature object
     */
    // afterFeature: function (uri, feature) {



    // },

    /**
     * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
     * @param {String} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
     * @param {Object} error error object if any
     */
    // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
     * the test.
     * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // after:async function (result, capabilities, specs) {
    //   //  await browser.pause(6000);
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
     * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
     * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
     */
    // onComplete: function (exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
       

    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed when a refresh happens.
    * @param {String} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
    * @param {String} newSessionId session ID of the new session
    */
    //onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
    //}
}
```

package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@axe-core/webdriverio": "^4.4.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/register": "^7.17.7",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^7.19.1",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.19.1",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.19.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.19.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.19.1",
    "appium": "^1.22.3",
    "appium-chromedriver": "^5.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^101.0.0",
    "wdio": "^6.0.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2",
    "wdio-cucumber-reporter": "^0.0.2",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^4.4.0",
    "wdio-viewport-size": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

These are my cucumber project configuration . i am running my emulator and real device both working , i am also running IOS simulator thats also working good . if u wanna check cumcumber settings i can help.

you need android studio installed and environment variables set so your system can run adb commands.
you also need to set JAVA_HOME environment variables in your system .

for IOS you need xcode installed .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using appium global on service try this. In my case, this configuration only worked with `127.0.0.1`, not `localhost`:

```
services: [ 
    ['appium' , { 
        args:{
            address:'127.0.0.1',
            port: 4724
        },
        logPath:'./',
        command: 'appium' 
    }
    ]
],
```